# Deploy To Heroku Breaks App (Node, Yarn, Webpack 3, Angular 1.6)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, webpack, yarnpkg

I've been learning Webpack to transition from Bower. I've built a basic Angular(1.6.6) app on NodeJS(8.9.1) using Webpack(3.8.1) and Yarn(1.3.2); however, I get "Internal Server Error" when run on Heroku. Deploys fine, though, and works perfectly in localhost.

In my research, I've learned that Webpack needs to be in dependencies instead of devDependencies. Fixing this may have prevented other errors, but I have the same problem.

Heroku logs blame ejs, but I doubt that is the real problem:

> Error: Could not find include include file.
>   at includeSource (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:276:17)
>   at getIncludePath (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:152:13)
>   at /app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:629:26
>   at Array.forEach ()
>   at Template.generateSource (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:605:15)
>   at Template.compile (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:509:12)
>   at Object.compile (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:358:16)
>   at handleCache (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:201:18)
>   at tryHandleCache (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:14)
>   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]
>   (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)

My package.json:

```
{ "name": "Simple Project",  
    "version": "0.1.0",  
    "description": "Simple Project",  
    "main": "server.js",  
    "scripts": {  
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",  
        "build": "webpack",  
        "start": "node server.js",  
        "postinstall": "webpack -p",  
        "heroku-prebuild": "webpack -p"  
    },  
    "repository": {  
        "type": "git",  
        "url": "git+https://github.com/Simple/Project.git"  
    },  
    "keywords": [],  
    "author": "Name",  
    "license": "MIT",  
    "bugs": {  
        "url": "https://github.com/Simple/Project/issues"  
    },  
    "homepage": "https://github.com/Simple/Project#readme",  
    "devDependencies": {  
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",  
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",  
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",  
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",  
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",  
        "file-loader": "^1.1.5",  
        "ng-annotate-loader": "^0.6.1",  
        "node-sass": "^4.6.1",  
        "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",  
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",  
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",  
        "url-loader": "^0.6.2"  
    },  
    "dependencies": {  
        "angular": "^1.6.6",  
        "angular-animate": "^1.6.6",  
        "angular-resource": "^1.6.6",  
        "angular-route": "^1.6.6",  
        "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.5.6",  
        "ejs": "^2.5.7",  
        "express": "^4.16.2",  
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",  
        "webpack": "^3.8.1"  
    },  
    "engines": {  
        "node": "^8.9.1",  
        "yarn": "^1.3.2"  
}}
```

I've set Webpack to put all .js, vendor files, and styles into /dist which is .gitignore(d) in my git, but **NOT** in my push to Heroku. You can check out my git here:

> https://github.com/SalamanderMike/portfolio

I've been researching this for a couple days and the answer hasn't revealed itself. I'm hoping someone can help me figure it out. I'm sure it's a simple thing I am overlooking. Thanks for your help!

Comment: check again on ur 'package.json.scripts'  where you show 'webpack' 3 diff times. Why do u need it run more than 1 time on a prod install to heroku.  You could unpack the docs on heroku/Node to see exactly where in install u want 'webpack' to be called???

Comment: I removed all the scripts except for "start": "node server.js". No effect. Same error. It almost seems as though node_modules are not being built in Heroku.

Comment: double check your local node ver also "8.9.1" using nvm or the like